# How to apply Apache server config to multiple paths?

Tags: apache, configuration

I have a set of Apache configuration settings (in apache.conf) contained within a `<Directory /srv/*/public>` block which are intended to apply to any public directory.

However, for some of the sites hosted on this server, the public directory is nested one level deeper (so the required path would be `/srv/*/app/public`), and so the directives in the Directory block are failing to be applied to these, even though I'd like them to be.

I don't want to duplicate the contents of the whole Directory block (it contains quite a lot of directives), but I can't find any way to apply it to two separate paths, and Apache's [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) suggest that no use of wildcards can match paths of different depths (since the `*` doesn't match a `/`).

What's the best way to do this?